# Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount or exceed gas limit

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I keep getting the error please check your gas amount or exceed gas limit.

The truffle config file

```
module.exports = {
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 8545,
            network_id: '*', // Match any network id,
            gas: 4712388,
            gasPrice: 65000000000,
        },
        solc: {
            optimizer: {
                enabled: true,
                runs: 200,
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Error displaying on console while migrating - `truffle migrate` and I am running in `ganache-cli` client and even `truffle develop` throws the same error

```
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... 0x3d291bb6431ee53a9fa794b750c39cd08939a4136b69f228287b26326f261990
  Migrations: 0xa936288081412d5f6dbfbb7e8c15526c3a51b47b
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x124e61a2327c00a9cc478c81f169fdd2568bf38eeb5dba4deb8677ddbf324744
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_application_migration.js
  Deploying Applications...
  ... 0x40e181355f93e1b0fb6e99137d5a87160b5c6b22061b9703718708918d6d8184
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
    at Object.callback (/Users/ajainvivek/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/contract.js:147:1)
    at /Users/ajainvivek/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/method.js:142:1
    at /Users/ajainvivek/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:89:1
    at /Users/ajainvivek/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-migrate/index.js:225:1
    at /Users/ajainvivek/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/ajainvivek/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/Users/ajainvivek/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/Users/ajainvivek/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/Users/ajainvivek/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/ajainvivek/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Can someone please help here. Its terribly annoying.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with setting constructor to be internal, I had to change it to public

```
function Applications() public {  // changed from internal to public
    applicant = msg.sender;
  }
```

unfortunately, the error was misleading in console